# WebStorm 11 - unresolved method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webstorm

I just download webStorm and everything works just fine except im getting this annoying markings when i usr $().
It says: **unresolved function or method or ajax()**

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: Did you [configure WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html) to recognize it?

Comment: i solved it! thank you!

Comment: Not the case here, but for a node-js project, run "npm install" to make all dependencies available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add JQuery to Javascript libraries in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`: either press `Download...` and then select `JQuery 2.0` from official libraries list, or use `Add...` button to specify a path to jquery.js. See also http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/