# jQuery .ajaxComplete() unresolved function or method. But it does work

Tags: jquery

The function does work though, but there is warning `Unresolved function or method` in my IDE (PhpStorm). Which confuses me.
The code is in a `<script>` tag in a Blade/Html view. Some lines above the ajaxcomplete() is the ajax request defined.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    const desktop = jQuery('div[id^="desktop"]');
    const mobile = jQuery('div[id^="mobile"]');
    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
        const width = $(window).width();
        if (width >= 700) {
            $(desktop).show();
            $(mobile).hide()
        } else if (width < 700) {
            $(desktop).hide();
            $(mobile).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Couldn't find anything on it on google, or I just overlooked it.

Comment: If you click the error in the console it should take you to the line of code which should tell you what the unresolved function is.

Comment: Also note that `desktop` and `mobile` are already jQuery objects so you don't need to wrap them again. Just `desktop.show()` etc will work fine. However I would strongly suggest you do this in CSS using media queries as it performs *much* better than JS.

Comment: Fergot to mention, the warning shows up in my IDE ( PHPStorm ). not the console. Sorry! And will remove the wraps around the constants :P thanks! @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: This seems to be a settings issue in PHPStorm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819652/webstorm-11-unresolved-method. Let me know if that fixes the problem

Comment: Ah, alright, Didn't google that good it seems. Will look into it thanks!

Comment: I don't know about your specific problem but I think you should show or hide the elements from CSS using media queries

Comment: Tried that, didn't work for some reasons. So I tried it with jQuery, and it works fine. Would problems with performance eventually occur with using jQuery to hide/show elements? @ToniMichelCaubet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This seems to be a settings issue in PHPStorm: stackoverflow.com/questions/34819652/…. Let me know if that fixes the problem – Rory McCrossan

This comment with the link to a similair issue, helped me fix it.

Thanks @RoryMcCrossan !